# AEM 6.2: multiple classes implementing Preprocessor. Which one is picked first?

Tags: aem

I created two classes (eg MyClass1 & MyClass2) implementing the com.day.cq.replication.Preprocessor interface.

In both I override the preprocess() and add logs.

When I activate a page, always MyClass1 (for eg) log statements are printed first.
What is the reason for this and how can I control which of the Preprocessor class should be picked first?

My class looks like below:

```
@Service(Preprocessor.class)
@Component(metatype = true, 
label="Class One",
description="Do something")
public class MyClass1 implements Preprocessor {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass1.class);


@Reference
private Replicator replicator;

/**
 *
 * 
 * @see Preprocessor#preprocess(ReplicationAction, ReplicationOptions)
 */
@Override
public void preprocess(ReplicationAction action, ReplicationOptions options) 
throws ReplicationException {
LOG.info("In MyClass1")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the order can be controlled. Are you sure creating multiple pre-processors is the best way to handle your requirement?

Comment: I believe they are called in the order they were registered. Usually any osgi based service lookup tend to follow the service ranking property, but I know from  experience that this is not the case with replication preprocessor. I might be wrong though.

Comment: yes, I read about service ranking but not sure where exactly define it. Do you or anyone have an example?

Comment: @awd - you seem to be right. The replication preprocessor does not seem to change call order based on service ranking

Comment: It would really depend on the data structure that the replicator is using for storing the preprocessors. I tried decompiling to view the code and it looks like preprocessors are stored in a `HashMap`. So I'm not sure the order of execution can be controlled using osgi service rankings.

Answer (score 0):

If order mattered for Preprocessor services, you would see that documented in it's JavaDoc, for example, the [6.3 doc does not mention order](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/Preprocessor.html)

> I don't believe there is a way to specify order, however, you may want to open a day care ticket and have adobe tell you if it's possible since they have the sourcecode.

You could **try** and provide a service ranking and test if that works and let us know.

here is your service with the lowest ranking possible:

> I basically added the annotation `@Property` with the OSGI service ranking name. You can also change the `intValue` to the highest possible int `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and see if that works.

```
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

@Service(Preprocessor.class)
@Component(metatype = true, 
label="Class One",
description="Do something")
@Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, intValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE) // < -----------------
public class MyClass1 implements Preprocessor {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass1.class);


@Reference
private Replicator replicator;

/**
 *
 * 
 * @see Preprocessor#preprocess(ReplicationAction, ReplicationOptions)
 */
@Override
public void preprocess(ReplicationAction action, ReplicationOptions options) 
throws ReplicationException {
LOG.info("In MyClass1")
    }
}
```

good luck!

Comment: I already tried that, as you mentioned and also differently i.e. 
@Properties({
    @Property(name=Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, intValue=Integer.MAX_VALUE)
})
Both cases didn't work..
Thanks for the response